# Registering Excel-DNA Add-In

Tags: excel-dna

I've followed the instructions to set up my XLL in the registry using the key:

```
Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options
```

Under that key, I'm using the entry `OPEN`, providing the value `\R [somepath here]`

My understanding is that this should register the Excel-DNA XLL to automatically load going forward -- this is not happening.

Can anyone point out where else I need to be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OPEN key should work.
For the seconds and subsequent add-ins, you'd add keys called "OPEN1", "OPEN2" etc.

But easiest is just to press "Alt+t, i" to get the add-ins dialog, then browse and pick your add-in here.